# Read latest Data Entered in File through Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script which give me count of particular string in a text file which created whenever my service refreshes, but sometimes I have to refresh the service couple of times in a day and the data in the text file is not override instead it append the data in the text file,

I need to make sure that whenever my Service refresh and data append in the text file, my script reads latest data and return me latest count of that string not the old one

How can i get my script to perform the same action

Below is the script which i am using

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Thread Name, Connected Thread
set today=%date%
set today=!today:/=!
set loc="D:\UserPath\UserPath1\Count%today%.DBG"
set val=
       for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ('find /c /i "Database Name:CitidbCzech01" %loc% 2^>nul') do (
       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       set val=%%~a
       set val=!val:---------- D:\UserPath\UserPath1\Count%today%.DBG:=!
       set val=!val: =!
       echo.Czech Thread,!val!
       endlocal
       )
endlocal
```

Comment: easier: `for /f %%a in ('type "%loc%" ^|find /c /I "Database Name:CitidbCzech01"') do echo Thread,%%a`. The inner `setlocal / endlocal` is not needed. Why would it show an old value? You scan the current file, so you should get a current value.

Comment: You could consider saving the last recorded instance's line number in a holding file, then start your next search from that point. Otherwise save the count to a holding file then use simple arithmetic to remove 'lastCount' from 'thisCount' to get the count since last check value.